# Error occuring in plotting thin plate spline model

Tags: r, mgcv

```
library(mgcv)
#Input dataset
vo2max<-read.csv('C:/Users/Dell/Desktop/Paper(2009)/vo2max.csv')
model1 <- gam(VO2max ~ s(Load, Speed, m=4,  bs=c("tp", data = vo2max) 
x <- range(vo2max$Load)
x <- seq(x[1], x[2], length.out=14)
y <- range(vo2max$Speed)
y <- seq(y[1], y[2], length.out=14)
z <- outer(x,y,
           function(Load,Speed)
             predict(model1, data.frame(Load,Speed)))
p <- persp(x,y,z, theta=30, phi=30,
           col="yellow",expand = 0.5,shade = 0.2, ticktype = "detailed",
           xlab="Load", ylab="Speed", zlab="VO2max")
obs<- trans3d(vo2max$Load, vo2max$Speed,vo2max$VO2max,p)
pred<- trans3d(vo2max$Load, vo2max$Speed,fitted(model1),p)`enter code here`
points(obs, col="red",pch=16)
segments(obs$x, obs$y, pred$x, pred$y)
predict(model1)
```

The dataset contains 14 values.  I need to plot a thin plate spline and predict the model,but I'm getting error in smooth construct. Whether I have to use any other library package. Help me in  providing the appropriate code.

Comment: Please provide the entire error message, as well as a [mcve].

Comment: If you have 14 observations you don't really have enough data to even attempt this. People have told you this already and you keep posting questions that don't seem to accept this point. You're making things worse by putting a 4th derivative penalty on the smooth (typically `m = 2`). You're failing to close the parentheses around the `s(....)` term and around `c("tp"`. To even begin, `s(Load, Speed, k = 14)` is the most you can possibly hope to fit, and likely `k` needs to be lower unless you have 14 unique data combinations of `Load` and `Speed`.

Comment: Were you looking for thin plate spline interpolation? If so, that is *not* what the thin plate splines in *mgcv* are for. If you wanted the interpolation method, see the *fields* package